# R how to adjust day of week to local timezone?

Tags: r

I have series of data, in date format like "2015010119", meaning "20150101"-the date, and "19"-the time.
I need to adjust these bulk data sets into different timezones. How can I adjust the hour, and based on the hour adjust the date then the day of week?

Anyone can help? Thank you very much!

Comment: It's certainly doable. What is your base timezone that the time is recorded at? Can you show exactly what you want as a final output?

Comment: The base timezone is US eastern time. I manually adjust the hour to Japan, UK and other timezones. But there's still a bias in day of week. I am try to adjust the date and hour record to something like "2017010207JP", with adjusted date, hour and timezone abbreviation. Also based on it, generate local day of week for different countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the date/time into a date format R understands, then you can adjust its `tzone` (timezone) attribute at will and extract the correct weekday using the base R's `weekdays` command.

```
> test_time <- as.POSIXct("2015010119",format="%Y%m%d%H",tz="America/New_York")
[1] "2015-01-01 19:00:00 EST"
> weekdays(test_time)
[1] "Thursday"
> attributes(test_time)$tzone <- "Japan"
> test_time
[1] "2015-01-02 09:00:00 JST"
> weekdays(test_time)
[1] "Friday"
```